# Create a new Pixel Emulator with Back/Forward gesture disabled

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have a suite of Appium tests which use a lot of swiping back and forth gestures, the new Pixel device functions to get which navigate back and forward when swiping the screen get in the way of these tests and end up exiting the app! I hope to create these emulators on the fly via the command line, is there some argument I can pass to turn this option off? Doing it manually via settings isn't viable here

https://imgur.com/a/LQLKSEH